# Place equivalence arrows in stackrel command one below the other in align environment

Tags: align

I'm trying to place the equivalence arrows one below the other in the align environment. But the equivalence arrows are in a `\stackrel` command and include a reference, so they are a bit displaced because the align environment aligns the `\stackrel` and not the equivalence arrows. How can I align it at the equivalence arrows?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\let\iff\Leftrightarrow

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\boxed{{z_1}} \boxed \leq \boxed{{z_2}} &\iff [(z_1, 1)] \boxed \leq [(z_2, 1)]
\\ &\stackrel{2.18(e)}{\iff} \exists n \in \mathbb{N}_0, m \in \mathbb{N}: [(z_2, 1)] = [(z_1, 1)] \boxed + [(n, m)]
\\ &\stackrel{2.18(a)}{\iff} \exists n \in \mathbb{N}_0, m \in \mathbb{N}: [(z_2, 1)] = [(z_1m + n, m)]
\\ &\stackrel{2.17}{\iff} \exists n \in \mathbb{N}_0, m \in \mathbb{N}: z_2m = z_1 m + n. \tag*{(*)}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: latex image]

PS: I defined for aesthetical reasons

```
\let\iff\Leftrightarrow
```

so these equivalence arrows are shorter than usual.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete but small document, which we can test as it is.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `array` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\let\iff\Leftrightarrow

\begin{document}
    \[\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
\begin{array}[b]{rcl}
\boxed{{z_1}} \boxed \leq \boxed{{z_2}} 
&\iff & 
    [(z_1, 1)] \boxed \leq [(z_2, 1)] \\ 
&\stackrel{2.18(e)}{\iff} &
    \exists n \in \mathbb{N}_0, m \in \mathbb{N}: [(z_2, 1)] = [(z_1, 1)] \boxed + [(n, m)]    \\
&\stackrel{2.18(a)}{\iff} &
    \exists n \in \mathbb{N}_0, m \in \mathbb{N}: [(z_2, 1)] = [(z_1m + n, m)]    \\
&\stackrel{2.17}{\iff} & 
    \exists n \in \mathbb{N}_0, m \in \mathbb{N}: z_2m = z_1 m + n. \tag*{(*)}
\end{array}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But how can I handle the (*) on the right which is now in the middle of the lines?

Comment: @Thomas, now in answer consider your request.

Answer (score 1):

Use `array`. I also suggest adding personal commands and correct relation and operation spacing around the boxed symbols.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,array}

\renewcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\N}{\numberset{N}}

\newcommand{\Bleq}{\mathrel{\boxed{\leq}}}
\newcommand{\Bplus}{\mathbin{\boxed{+}}}
\newcommand{\Bobj}[1]{\boxed{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt} % local setting
\begin{array}[b]{r >{{}}c<{{}} l}
\Bobj{z_1} \Bleq \Bobj{z_2}
  & \iff & [(z_1, 1)] \Bleq [(z_2, 1)]
\\[\jot]
  &\overset{2.18(e)}{\iff} & \exists n \in \N_0, m \in \N \mathpunct:
                               [(z_2, 1)] = [(z_1, 1)] \Bplus [(n, m)]
\\[\jot]
  &\overset{2.18(a)}{\iff} & \exists n \in \N_0, m \in \N \mathpunct:
                               [(z_2, 1)] = [(z_1m + n, m)]
\\[\jot]
  &\overset{2.17}{\iff}    & \exists n \in \N_0, m \in \N \mathpunct:
                                z_2m = z_1 m + n.
\end{array}
\tag*{(*)}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different realization (which I'd prefer):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,array}

\renewcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\N}{\numberset{N}}

\newcommand{\Bleq}{\mathrel{\boxed{\leq}}}
\newcommand{\Bplus}{\mathbin{\boxed{+}}}
\newcommand{\Bobj}[1]{\boxed{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\Bobj{z_1} \Bleq \Bobj{z_2}
  &\iff  [(z_1, 1)] \Bleq [(z_2, 1)]
\\
  &\iff \exists n \in \N_0, m \in \N \mathpunct: [(z_2, 1)] = [(z_1, 1)] \Bplus [(n, m)]
  &&\text{by 2.18(e)}
\\
  &\iff \exists n \in \N_0, m \in \N \mathpunct: [(z_2, 1)] = [(z_1m + n, m)]
  &&\text{by 2.18(a)} \vphantom{\Bplus}
\\
  &\iff \exists n \in \N_0, m \in \N \mathpunct: z_2m = z_1 m + n
  &&\text{by 2.17} \smash[b]{\vphantom{\Bplus}}
  \tag*{(*)}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can place the upper elements in `\stackrel` in a `\mathclap` and then add additional spaces `~` as needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts}

\let\iff\Leftrightarrow

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \boxed{{z_1}} \boxed \leq \boxed{{z_2}} 
    &\iff [(z_1, 1)] \boxed \leq [(z_2, 1)] \\
    &\stackrel{\mathclap{2.18(e)}}{\iff} ~~ \exists n \in \mathbb{N}_0, m \in \mathbb{N}: [(z_2, 1)] = [(z_1, 1)] \boxed + [(n, m)] \\
    &\stackrel{\mathclap{2.18(a)}}{\iff} ~~ \exists n \in \mathbb{N}_0, m \in \mathbb{N}: [(z_2, 1)] = [(z_1 m + n, m)] \\
    &\stackrel{\mathclap{2.17}}{\iff}    ~~ \exists n \in \mathbb{N}_0, m \in \mathbb{N}: z_2 m = z_1 m + n.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```